# Can whether or not a phone call was answered be confirmed from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, phone-call

I already know how to call a phone number from within an app. What I'm wondering is whether there's any way to confirm whether or not that call was answered (just getting a boolean of whether it happened would be good enough)? I suspect the answer would be "no" since the app is basically just giving a one-way communication message to the phone to call the number. However, I thought I'd double check with this community before I give up on finding a way to do it. This particular feature is meant for an enterprise app, so I'm able to use any tool available to make this happen, regardless of what Apple has to say about it.

Comment: Not necessarily true about Enterprise Apps. I believe that Apple still has the final say because you still need to get Apple approval before launching an Enterprise App (to my knowledge, though I have never done it before)

Comment: Nah, Apple doesn't have any say at all. You don't go through the App Store or get approval from anybody. I've deployed a few apps internally at my company already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CoreTelephony Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603) to see what's available. It depends on your exact circumstances as to how accurate you can get...